# Format being modified automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a macro on vba that modifies the format automatically when a table changes structure.

So, looking at this example.

Imagine we have the following file:

[image: I1]

And now we modify the family tree structure to the following:

[image]

As you can see the table in the right is not fitting the tree structure (grey cells are supposed to be for parents and also the table needs to have more rows in the end).

I have no idea on how to even start this. Could you please give me a hint?

The final result (after running the macro) should be this:

[image]

Comment: There is no need to use VBA, simple conditional formatting checking if parent column is not empty should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in the rows and columns as shown in the picture below, you can use conditional formatting based on equations to get the desired result. I was able to come up with five (5) rules (*order is important!*) which also maintains the borders with the internal dashed-lines.

Note: for the cells in columns A-C, if you drag cells from one location to another, it'll disrupt the conditional formatting (copy/paste works fine).

[image: sample table which matches data placement for sample formatting]

The conditional formatting rules (by default) are added in so that the most recently added is on the top of the list. For this reason, I will go through each rule from bottom to top.

[image: order of conditional formatting rules, and columns they're applied to.]

---

The formula used for this rule is: `=NOT(AND(ISBLANK($A1),ISBLANK($B1),ISBLANK($C1)))`

Note from the formatting preview that there are dashed lines completely surrounding the cell. *There is also a **white** background/fill.* The fill color is important, as it "undos" the fill formatting for the parent rows if they get moved.

[image: lowest formatting rule]

The main changes for the other two rules with dashed lines is which column each rule is applied to and which side has a solid border instead of a dash. You can see from the second picture that the rule with the right solid-border is applied to the right-most table column, and that the rule with the left solid-border is applied to the left-most table column.

The formula for both of these is the same as the equation used in the prior rule: `=NOT(AND(ISBLANK($A1),ISBLANK($B1),ISBLANK($C1)))`. Also as in the prior rule, these rules have a **white** fill.

---

For the next rule (second from the top), the equation is: `=AND(NOT(AND(ISBLANK($A1),ISBLANK($B1),ISBLANK($C1))),AND(ISBLANK($A2),ISBLANK($B2),ISBLANK($C2)))` and the formatting is a solid border on the bottom of the cell. This rule does **not** have any fill color.

[image: formatting rule for second from the top]

For the last rule (top-most one) the equation is fairly simple: `=NOT(ISBLANK($B1))`.

The formatting is a solid border across the top and the bottom of the cell. The fill color is whichever color you want for the parent rows.

[image: formatting rule for top condition]

Comment: Wow thank you, that was actually really helpful! Last question, to create a thick border outside all the cells containing the format you said?

Comment: @MTT Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The way conditional formatting is applied, is cell by cell. That's why there are three different rules with any border: The one with border to the left, the one with border to the right, and the one with a border on the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

If your Parents are in Column B, Sons in Column C and your table from Column E to I, then the following code will apply the grey colour to the table rows and also remove and add the outside border as the list grows.

*(On a separate note, shouldn't son be child instead?)*

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on column C, where the Son/Child is

For i = 3 To LastRow
'loop through row 3 to last to colour in grey the Parent rows
    If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
        ws.Range("E" & i & ":I" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Else
        ws.Range("E" & i & ":I" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone
        'if not a parent row, then remove color from row
    End If
Next i

    With ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow)
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
    'above remove outside border from your table
    'below re-apply the border to your table
    With ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    ws.Range("E1:I" & LastRow).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub
```